# why the color of \\ in my 'texstudio' is red?

Tags: texstudio

I want to make this table.

[image]

I can make table like figure above with this code:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$P(X=x,Y=y)$}}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$Y=y$}\\
        \cline{3-5}
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}&1&3&5\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{$X=x$}&2&$0.1$&$0.2$&$0.1$\\
        \cline{2-5}
        &4&$0.15$&$0.3$&$0.15$\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to ask, why the color of `\\` in my 'texstudio' is red?

[image]

Comment: Hover over the highlighting. It will probably tell you "cols in tabular missing". That's because it doesn't understand that \multicolumn takes two columns, so it only counts 4. Ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mysterious (to me) reasons, in that context TeXStudio counts the number of `&` characters from the previous `\\` and marks differently a `\\` if the count doesn't match the expected number.

Apparently this count mechanism is not aware of `\multicolumn`.

Don't worry, the document is OK (apart from the usage of `letter`, of course).